# Adding files and folders using cx_Freeze

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I definitively switched from py2exe to cx_Freeze, at the moment I can say it works great for me, I only have some problems with its documentation that is not totally clear to me and it is controversial because around the web there are working solutions totally different from those I found on the official documentation. Especially I did not find a solution to copy both single files located in different source folders and complete folders. For instance I would like that cx_Freeze copies everything from `src/locales` to `src/build/exe.win-amd64-3.8/locales` and `src/key.ico` to `src/build/exe.win-amd64-3.8/key.ico`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `include_files` option of the `build_exe` command should provide the solution you are looking for. According to the [cx_Freeze documentation](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/distutils.html#build-exe):

> list containing files to be copied to the target directory; it is expected that this list will contain strings or 2-tuples for the source and destination; the source can be a file or a directory (in which case the tree is copied except for .svn and CVS directories); the target must not be an absolute path

Accordingly, try the following in your `setup.py` file:

```py
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

build_exe_options = {"include_files": ["locales", "key.ico"],
                     ...
                    }

setup(
    ...
    options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
    ...
)
```

With this, cx_Freeze should make the expected copies, provided your `setup.py` file is located in `src` and you run the command

```
python setup.py build
```

from there as well.